# regex_search() equivalent in C

Tags: c, regex

I came across this function in C++ regex_search https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-to-find-all-match-of-a-regex-in-a-string/ using which you can find all the occurences of the matching patterns/substrings.
How can I implement this in C using regcomp and regexec?

I wrote this program to traverse the entire string to find all the matching substrings. But getting segmentation fault. Could you please tell me how I can fix it to find both the places where "foo=" is found?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <regex.h>
    //#include <bits/stdc++.h>
    #define MAXMATCH 20

    int main () {

            char reg[81]="foo=";           /* Regular Expresion */
            char *org_str= "here is the foo=bar and xmxmxmx now foo=baz";        /* Strings to match against */
            char test[81];         /* String to hold matched elememts */
            regex_t exp;

            const char *data_buf;
            regmatch_t matches[MAXMATCH];   /* Array of matches */
            int status;
            int i;
            int numchars;


            /* Let's use extended regular expresssions */

            status = regcomp(&exp,reg,REG_EXTENDED);

            /* Leave program if regex is faulty */
            /* we could use regerror to decode the error ... */
            if (status) return 1;

                    data_buf = org_str;
                    status = regexec(&exp,data_buf,MAXMATCH,matches,0) ;
            return 0;

      }
```

I got to know that regexec matches at the max N number of substrings defined by MAXMATCH. How to handle the situation where we don't know the maximum of matching patterns found in the input string?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of `i` in `numchars = (int)matches[i].rm_eo - (int)matches[i].rm_so;`?

Answer (score 1):

The C language itself does not define any regex engine. If you're targeting POSIX, however, the `regcomp` and `regexec` functions provide this functionality for the two traditional flavors of "regex": BRE (used by plain `grep` and `sed`, and which is not actually regular) and ERE (used by `grep -E` and most modern things. For more variants of regex (Perl, JS, etc.) you'll need a third-party library.

Comment: Note that question was completely edited after this answer was posted.